# Filters using image-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image-processing, openseadragon

I am trying to add morphological filters to an openseadragon viewer using image-js. Can I add filters directly on a fabricjs canvas? I am not sure if image-js supports fabricjs overlays. If it is not supported then which methods/libraries can I use to add morphological filters?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanting to filter the image in the viewer, and not overlay content, right? There is https://github.com/altert/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay for Fabric overlays, but that's probably not what you want.

For filtering the image in the viewer, these are the main options:

https://github.com/usnistgov/OpenSeadragonFiltering

https://github.com/thejohnhoffer/viaWebGL

You probably want to start with OpenSeadragonFiltering, as it works on canvas. I'm not familiar with image-js, but maybe it can operate on the canvas that OpenSeadragonFiltering exposes?